# Pop-up background not covering navigation bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

### Explanation

I have this pop-up showing when clicking a button, but for some reason, when displayed, the background isn't covering the navigation bar. I've already tried to change the z-index, but nothing happens. It'll only cover the navigation bar when there's no animation.

### Code

You can also see it in [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/5p8d70jx/) ([full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/5p8d70jx/embedded/result/)).

```js
var custom = function() {

  var handlePopup = function() {
    var overlay = $('.popup-overlay'),
      close = $('.popup-close'),
      trigger = $('.popup-trigger'),
      parent = $('.popup-container');

    trigger.on('click', function() {
      $(this).closest('.popup-container').addClass('popup-overlay-show');
    });

    close.on('click', function(e) {
      e.stopPropagation();
      parent.removeClass('popup-overlay-show');
    });
  }

  return {
    init: function() {
      handlePopup();
    },
  };
}();

$(document).ready(function() {
  custom.init();
});
```

```css
.navbar {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.overlay {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.btn {
  margin-top: 100px;
}

.popup-overlay {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  opacity: 0;
  visibility: hidden;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.55);
}

.popup-overlay-show {
  z-index: 1;
}

.popup-overlay-show .popup-overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  visibility: visible;
  z-index: 2000 !important;
}

.popup-content {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  width: 600px;
  height: auto;
  background: #fff;
  padding: 35px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </header>

    <div class="popup-container">

      <div class="popup-trigger animated fadeInUp">
        <div class="overlay">
          <a class="btn btn-default" href="#" role="button">Open</a>
        </div>
        <div class="popup-overlay">
          <div class="popup-content">
            <a href="javascript:void(0);" class="popup-close">Close</a>
            <div class="row">
              <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
              </p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Thanks in advance,
Luiz.

Comment: This happens because you use `transform: translate3d(0, -50%, 0);` which moves you into 3 dimensions. A new stacking order is created when you move into 3D and your z-index values won't work.

Comment: Why are you using a custom modal when you should use bootstrap's modal? using bootstraps modal should fix all your issues. You can style a modal however you'd like btw.

Comment: @Ihazkode I deleted this `transform` code to see if it would work, but nothing happens still :(

Comment: @Iscmaro Great idea!! I'll try to adapt this modal (which wasn't made by me) to the Bootstrap's one.

Comment: I just put that as an example. The issue comes from Animate.css The class `fadeInUp` has the following keyframes

`@keyframes fadeInUp{0%{opacity:0;transform:translate3d(0,100%,0)}to{opacity:1;transform:none}}` That's why your code works if you remove the animation.

Comment: @Luiz give my answer a try.. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try This CSS

CSS

```
.navbar {
  background-color: yellow;
  z-index:10;
}

.popup-container{
  position: relative;
}

.popup-overlay-show {
    z-index: 16;
}
```

[Link For Reference](https://jsfiddle.net/DChandraShekhar/9ne5qzux/4/)

Answer (score 0):

As Iscmaro [suggested above](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45901034/pop-up-background-not-covering-navigation-bar#comment78761198_45901034), it's also possible to solve it by using [Bootstrap's modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#modals), as you can see below.

You can also see it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8vd7Lxh6/) ([full screen](http://jsfiddle.net/8vd7Lxh6/embedded/result/)).

```css
.navbar {
    background-color: yellow;
}

.btn {
    margin-top: 100px;
}

.vertical-alignment-helper {
    display: table;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}

.vertical-align-center {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/3.5.2/animate.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>
    <header class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default animated fadeInUp" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">Open</button>

    <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="vertical-alignment-helper">
            <div class="modal-dialog vertical-align-center">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">
                        Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</body>

</html>
```